# Initializing MVC model properties using constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC model.

```
public class ProtocolSummary
{
    public string MasteredTask { get; set; }
    public string NewTask { get; set; }

    public List<AssistTech> ATList { get; set; }
}

public class AssistTech
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string ScheduleForUse { get; set; }
    public string StorageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

How to initialize this using an constructor?

Comment: So which class do you want to construct?  Why can't you just write a constructor?  Can you show the calling code where you would like to construct these?

Answer (score 2):

MVC model is a just a POCO.You can initialize it using default constructor and set the properties.Or better use object initializer

```
// Assuming you want an instance of ProtocolSummary
 var protocolSummary = new ProtocolSummary()
{
    MasteredTask = "Some Mastered task name",
    NewTask = "Here goes new task"
};
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to make Varinder Singh's answer more complete:

```
// Assuming you want an instance of ProtocolSummary
var protocolSummary = new ProtocolSummary()
{
MasteredTask = "Some Mastered task name",
NewTask = "Here goes new task",
ATList  = new List<AssistTech>() 
{
new AssistTech() { Type  = "Some text", ScheduleForUse  = "Some other text", StorageLocation  = "Some other other text" },
new AssistTech() { Type  = "Some text", ScheduleForUse  = "Some other text", StorageLocation  = "Some other other text" }
}
};
```